# Analog Clock cannot read the property of null

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain what I am missing here... the querySelector doesn't appear to be working as I am getting the error "cannot read the property of null" on line 10 my javascript.

```
const deg = 6;
const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
setInterval(() => {
        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
        let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
        hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)} deg)';
        mn.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${mm}deg)';
        sc.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${ss}deg)';
})
```

Here is the HTML...

```
    <div class="clock">
    <div class="hour">
        <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="min">
        <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sec">
        <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: 99.9% sure you are trying to find the element before it is rendered to the page.

Comment: Next issue is, you are using string literal syntax with a regular string.  `'${foo}'` !== `\`${foo}\``

Comment: Thanks epascarello... I moved it to the bottom of the page and I am getting the same result. Can you explain what I can do to resolve the literal/regular syntax?

Comment: change the quotes like in the example I gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

epascarello already gave you the solution but he told you it working here.

```js
const deg = 6;
const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
setInterval(() => {
        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
        let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
        hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)} deg)`;
        mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
        sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
})
```

```css
.clock > div >div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
    <div class="hour">
        <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="min">
        <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sec">
        <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```